# How do I use FileDescriptor with HTTP URLs

Tags: android, file-descriptor, file-uri

I was hoping this was going to work for getting Android's `MediaPlayer` to stream from a URL using authentication, but now I'm not so sure. I have no problem getting it to stream from an open server (no authentication) but I don't see any way to tell `MediaPlayer` to use basic authentication unless perhaps using the `FileDescriptor` argument works? So I tried this but got the following error:

```
IllegalArgumentException: Expected file scheme in URI http://www.myserver.com/music.mp3
```

My code looks something like this:

```
File f = new File(new URL("http://www.myserver.com/music.mp3").toURI());
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
mediaplayer.SetDataSource(fis.getFD());
```

Is it correct to say that a `FileDescriptor` can only be used with local `file://` URLs and not normal `http://` URLs? If so, does anyone have any other ideas on how to stream from a server that requires authentication using Android's `MediaPlayer`?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to say that a FileDescriptor can only be used with local file:// URL

No, that's incorrect, Java takes the Unix philosophy that "everything is a file" and the [javadoc reads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html):

> handle to the underlying machine-specific structure representing an open file, an open socket, or another source or sink of bytes.

However, the `MediaPlayer` can only open *seekable* file descriptors with [`setDataSource(FileDescriptor)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.io.FileDescriptor))

Maybe you can try something like this (untested)

```
URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();
// Authenticate the way you can
connection.setRequestProperty("HeaderName", "Header Value");

// Save into a file
File tmp = new File(getCacheDir(), "media");
InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tmp);
// TODO copy in into out
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tmp);
```

Comment: In this code, I am not seeing how the app knows that tmp has anything to do with the InputStream in.